# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

help me pls. Thank You!

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse ()
    at Object.success (app.js:102)

```
function checkpay(url)
{
    $('#ajaxLoader').show();
    $.get('http://'+window.location.host+'/order/'+url, function(data) {
        $('#ajaxLoader').hide();
        if(data != '')
        {
            var res = JSON.parse(data);     <-------------- 102 string here
            if(res.status == "ok")
            {
                $('#yt0').attr('onclick','window.location ="'+res.chkurl+'"');
                $('#yt0').val('Скачать');
            }
            else alert("Платеж не найден, попробуйте позже");
        }   
        else alert("Платеж не найден, попробуйте позже");

    });
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can't really help you with your corrupt JSON

Comment: tell me why...?

Comment: What does -> `102 string here` mean?..

Comment: i just show 102 string)) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse () at Object.success (app.js:102)

Comment: Well "102" is just the line number of your "app.js", what we really need is what does `data` equal.. Try placing a `console.log(data)` or look in your developer tools and see what's been returned.. eg. In chrome you can go to the network tab in develop tools and click on the request to see what was sent and received.

Comment: `console.log(data)` shows what?

Comment: `$('#yt0').attr('onclick','window.location ="'+res.chkurl+'"');` DO NOT DO THAT! Use `.on("click", function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$('#ajaxLoader').show();
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://'+window.location.host+'/order/'+url,
   type: 'GET',
   data: {},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
        $('#ajaxLoader').hide();
        if(data.hasOwnProperty('status'))
        {
          if(data.status == "ok"){
            $('#yt0').click(function(){
               window.location = data.chkurl;
            })
            $('#yt0').val('Скачать');
          }
        }
   }
})
```